# C: Generating hash keys for large data sets?

Tags: c, hash, key

I am currently playing around with hashing and key generation trying to make my own hash key generator.

At the moment I have a list of ~90000 strings (each 1 word and a different word).  I was wondering what the best way to generate keys (number keys not string keys) would be?

Currently depending on the words last ascii character I do a calculation based on the value of the letter.

The result is about 50% of the words generate a key that clashes with another.

I have used quadratic probing to then find space in the table for the rest of the words.

My question, as above, is what is generally the best sort of way to generate a key for 90000 different words?  I know that the larger the data set, the more likely there will be clashes, but how would you suggest/or minimise the clashes?

Edit: Also - I don't care about cryptography, it just needs to be fast.

Thanks.

Comment: How about `SHA512`? You could do a quite fast lookup with only 8 `uint64_t`s.

Comment: What is the fillfactor?  how many bits in the hashvalue ? What is your hashfunction ? Do you realise that there are only 26 possible values for the last character? (or 52, or 62 ...)

Comment: ...or use http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "borrow" [Java's implementation of `String`'s `hashCode`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.hashCode%28%29)<sup>*</sup>:

```
int hashCode(const char* s) {
    int h = 0;
    while (*s) {
        h = 31*h + (*s++);
    }
    return h;
}
```

This function achieves a reasonable separation, and is among the most widely used hash functions out there.

<sup>*</sup> which, [as it turns out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882784/c-generating-hash-keys-for-large-data-sets/14882862#comment20868704_14882862), Java in turn ["borrowed" from Kernighan & Ritchie's book](http://www.strchr.com/hash_functions) on C programming.

Comment: Isn't that the Kernighan hash? (or was that *33?)

Comment: @wildplasser it is indeed the Kerninghan hash, I just googled it: "Kernighan and Ritchie's function uses INITIAL_VALUE of 0 and M of 31."

Comment: @JerryCoffin I think that any add/multiply solution should beat the OP's implementation, simply by virtue of considering all characters. Heck, even a random, non-prime multiplier greater than `1` should do a better job than a function that is based squarely on the last character of the string.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No argument on that -- though as I recall, DJ Bernstein's isn't much (if any) extra work to implement, and is generally acknowledged as one of the best.

Answer (score 4):

To prevent clashes you need a good hash key generator.

There are several algorithms available.  One recent and very fast one is called [xxHash](http://code.google.com/p/xxhash/).  It's written in C.

Answer (score 0):

It cant be good choice choosing 90,000 size of the hash table, there is much better concept of  perfect hashing, according to this use double hashing one for table lookup and the other to maintain the list, you should try multiplication method for both, i think that's good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen Knuth use:

```
  register int h,k; register char *p;
  for (h=0,p=w;*p;p++) h=(*p+h+h)%hash_prime;
```

Where hash_prime is a prime larger than 4x the expected number of live entries in the hash table.

See: [Knuth's literateprogramming.com](http://www.literateprogramming.com/cweb_download.html), the Adventure example.

Here's the hashing code in context:

```
#define hash_prime 1009/* the size of the hash table */

typedef struct {
  char text[6]; /* string of length at most 5 */
  char word_type; /* a |wordtype| */
  char meaning;
} hash_entry;

hash_entry hash_table[hash_prime]; /* the table of words we know */

void new_word(w,m)
  char *w; /* a string of length 5 or less */
  int m; /* its meaning */
{
  register int h,k; register char *p;
  for (h=0,p=w;*p;p++) h=(*p+h+h)%hash_prime;
  while (hash_table[h].word_type) {
    h++;if (h==hash_prime) h=0;
}

int lookup(w)
  char *w; /* a string that you typed */
{
  register int h; register char *p; register char t;
  t=w[5]; w[5]='\0'; /* truncate the word */
  for (h=0,p=w;*p;p++) h=(*p+h+h)%hash_prime; /* compute starting address */
  w[5]=t; /* restore original word */
  if (h<0) return -1; /* a negative character might screw us up */
  while (hash_table[h].word_type) {
    if (streq(w,hash_table[h].text)) return h;
    h++;if (h==hash_prime) h=0;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Note, this code:

```
  register char t;
  // . . .
  t=w[5]; w[5]='\0'; /* truncate the word */
  // . . .
  w[5]=t; /* restore original word */
```

Are for a specific requirement to only look at the first 5 characters and should be removed so you hash the entire word.

Answer (score 0):

The term you want is avalanche - a hash function that provides optimal spread.

If you want your keys to be guaranteed to be unique, and if your dataset has zero duplicates
then you can convert your word as a base36 number into a base10 number.  If you use stroull() you can return really large integers

```
char *p=myword;
for(; *p; p++) 
  *p=toupper(*p);
unsigned long long key=strtoull(myword, NULL, 36);
```

This can overflow and still return a positive number.  Some hashes when given a long string may overflow a 32bit  integer. Kerneghan's hash and Bernstein's hash do that.

In reality and as pointed out by several other folks:

Consider that collisions are a function of the hash_table size and the avalanche of the hash_function modulo hash_table size.  Instead of truly unique keys what you  want may be a better hash_table algorithm and size.